# WCF Service Throttling

Tags: wcf, binding, service, tcp, throttling

I have used TCP bindings in my WCF service and at a time it is possible that many people connect to this service, my question is does i need to do service throttling in my wcf service if yes then what is the ideal way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The throttling provided out of the box by WCF is via the [`ServiceThrottlingBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735114.aspx). It is agnostic of the specific bindings you're using (i.e. tcp/http doesn't matter).

Comment: but this is partial answer to my question, still i will like to know ideal situation for using throttling

Comment: I was a little confused by that part of your question to be honest. The way to throttle is via ServiceThrottlingBehavior... there is no "ideal" in that sense. If you're asking how to discover what the ideal values are for the various configuration properties of STB, then there again is no "ideal". It all depends on the specifics of your service. The only way to discover what numbers make sense is via load testing on near production hardware and finding your peaks. Keep in mind there are a ton more switches and knobs you may want to play with before you arrive at final throttling values.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the situation: where/how the service is hosted, how it's accessed, etc.

There's no good single answer for your question.

Your service probably needs to be tested under expected loads and see how it handles.  With that information you should be able to begin to come up with a throttling plan, if testing shows that it's needed.

Comment: Terry say for example application can have 1500 users and i think on particular day 300-400 people may use application in parralel

Comment: I'm not sure that's enough information to make a decision based on.  It depends on how much work the service does, etc.  There will be no way, I don't think, to have a conclusive answer to your question without experimentation and load testing.  If I were you I'd start off with no throttling and then add it as you see that it's needed.

Comment: is right, it depends. WCF provides default service throttling as [described here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735114(v=vs.90).aspx) Start with the WCF defaults and build a load test set up that creates a realistic load. Watch the host resource utilization (primarily CPU & memory usage perf counters). Increase the load until you're consistently using more than 80% of any resources. This will be close to a real world max load. Next, tweak the defaults to see if you can get more throughput for the same max load or lower resource consumption. Rinse & repeat...

Comment: thanks @Terry and @Sixto, for suggestions will try the load testing before i implement the same